# data wrangling - match value in one column with values in others

Tags: r

I have data of the following format.

```
Noun   InCage   InHouse   InGarage   InTree
Bird   Bird     Dog       None       Cat
Cat    Bird     Dog       None       Cat
Dog    Bird     Dog       None       Cat
```

I'd like it in this format:

```
Noun    Place
Bird    InCage
Cat     InTree
Dog     InHouse
```

Short of writing a bunch of if statements, what's a smarter way to do this?

Here is the dput of the small example I mention.

```
structure(list(
    Item = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Bird", "Cat", 
    "Dog"), class = "factor"), InTree = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = "Cat", class = "factor"), InHouse = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "Dog", class = "factor"), InCage = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "Bird", class = "factor"), InGarage = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "none", class = "factor")), .Names = c("Item", "InTree", 
    "InHouse", "InCage", "InGarage"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tidyr` and `dplyr`.

First we `gather`, to make the data long, rather than wide. Then we `filter` to only keep those rows where item and animal match:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dat %>% gather(place, animal, -Item) %>%
        filter(as.character(Item) == as.character(animal))

  Item   place animal
1  Cat  InTree    Cat
2  Dog InHouse    Dog
3 Bird  InCage   Bird
```

Comment: Why not select(-Noun) then distinct()?

Comment: @bramtayl 1. You end up with `none` which was not asked for. 2. Less general - what if you have an Item more than once?

Answer (score 2):

This would be a fairly simple base solution using `stack` which is designed for this sort of problem. The `as.character` step is needed because the factor variables do not play well with the stacking operation, since the levels are not shared across all columns:

```
stack( lapply(res, as.character) )
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `apply` to operate on each row of your data:

```
cbind(df[1L], Place = apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x) names(df[-1L])[x[-1L] == x[1L]]))
#  Item   Place
#1  Cat  InTree
#2  Dog InHouse
#3 Bird  InCage
```

However, this might not be very fast for large datasets.